# linalg.lstsq with fixed slope?

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

Suppose that we have two arrays of data:
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4,6]
Obviously a linear fit would return a slope of 2 and an intercept of 0 and, of course, both routines in Numpy [`linalg.lstsq()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) and [`polyfit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) are successful. But they think of slope and intercept as parameters to search.

Is it possible to keep the slope fixed and define only the intercept ?

Answer (score 8):

If the fit equation is `y = a*x + b`, you can find the intercept `b` that best fits you data, given a fixed slope `a = A`, as:

```
b = np.mean(y - A*x)
```

If instead you had a fixed intercept `b = B` and wanted to find the slope best fitting your data, the math works out to:

```
a = np.dot(X, Y-B) / np.dot(X, X)
```

Comment: True, for a fast answer (which I actually used), but I was thinking of something that would take advantage of the algorithms in these routines.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no default built-in method to fix some of the parameters in the fit, although it is very straightforward to do if you know how this works internally. If you can suggest an interface, I can put together a PR for the next numpy release...

Comment: The least squares solution works out to be `b = np.mean(y) - A*np.mean(x)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `scipy.optimize.fsolve`:

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3])
Y = np.array([2, 4, 6])
s = 2

def f(i):
    """Fixed slope 1-deg polynomial residuals"""
    return ((Y - (s*X + i))**2).sum()
```

It performs about the same as `polyfit`:

```
In [37]: np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
Out[37]: array([  2.00000000e+00,   2.30755522e-15])

In [38]: fsolve(f, x0=1)
Out[38]: array([  1.63883763e-16])
```

And changing the slope:

```
In [39]: s = 4

In [40]: fsolve(f, x0=1)
Out[40]: array([-3.99075568])
```

We get a new optimum